# SQL Server and DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been spending hours of googleing and searching for a good way to solve my problem but I can't find anything.

I have two tables: table1 and table2 and i want to find all unique emails in table1 that are not present in table2.

The first query returns a int result of 1420 and the second query returns a row set with total count of 1431.

How is that possible? I guess it has something to do with the fact that i select name and status as well?

```
select 
    Count(DISTINCT(Email)) 
from
    table1 t1 
where 
    t1.siteId = 4 
    and t1.Email not in (select Email from table2 t2 where t2.SiteId = 4)
go

WITH MyPage AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT(t1.Email), 
       t1.Name, 
       t1.[Status],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by t1.Email ORDER BY t1.Name) AS Apperences,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.Name) AS RowNumber
   FROM 
       table1 t1 
   WHERE 
       t1.siteId = 4 
       AND t1.Email NOT IN (SELECT Email FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.SiteId = 4)
)
SELECT 
    Email, Name, [Status]
FROM 
    MyPage
WHERE 
    RowNumber => 0 and RowNumber <= 50000
```

I know that I could add "distinct" on the last select but that would screw up the paging that I would like to have...

Comment: [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) is applied to all columns in the `SELECT` clause, regardless of whether or not those parentheses are present.

Comment: Okey, so thats why shows another result when I add the name field? Is there a way arund that? To just apply distinct to one field?

Comment: If you have 2 different names with the same email, which one should you return?

Comment: It doesnt matter. When i look at the result the names are exactlly the same. Could it be an encoding issue?

Comment: You are running just a `Count(DISTINCT(Email))` in the first query and a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.email...` in the second query. What you get in the first query is the number of `DISTINCT` emails, while in the second query you are also getting the numbers of appearances also, which is why the row count increases. This is this simple. There's no real question here.

Comment: I was not aware of the fact that one could not use Distinct(email), name. I think I get the concept. My solution at the moment is to run the page query against an already filtered table

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH MyPage 
AS
  (SELECT 
      t1.Email, 
      t1.Name, 
      t1.[Status],
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by t1.Email ORDER BY t1.Name) AS Apperences,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.Name) AS RowNumber
   FROM table1 t1 
   WHERE t1.siteId = 4 
   and t1.Email not in (SELECT Email FROM table2 t2 where t2.SiteId=4)
  )

SELECT Email, Name, [Status]
FROM MyPage
WHERE RowNumber => 0 and RowNumber <= 50000
AND Apperences = 1 // this will give you the DISTINCT email
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all distinct emails and just one name applied to it, create a list of all distinct mails with a sample name (I use the last one in alphabetical order) first and then use this table as a base to add more information. However, the result, especially the row numbers will be useless.

```
    WITH MyPage AS
      (SELECT t1.Email, 
        t1.Name, 
        t1.[Status],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by t1.Email ORDER BY t1.Name) AS Apperences,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.Name) AS RowNumber
        FROM 
          (select x.Email, max(Name) as name 
             from table1 t1 
            where t1.siteId = 4 
              and t1.Email not in (
              SELECT Email FROM table2 t2 where t2.SiteId=4
              )
            group by x.Email
          ) t1
    SELECT Email, Name, [Status]
    FROM MyPage
    WHERE RowNumber => 0 and RowNumber <= 50000
```